# Queries behind Oracle EM Express

Tags: oracle, monitoring

I would like to write my own monitoring tool so that I do not have to use Oracle EM Express. EM Express is still using Flash and is slow and clunky.

S0 I want to figure out the queries behind it so I can build my own HTML5 Monitoring tool.  Performance tab and the Resources Tab are the two we use the most. Any insights to the queries behind these would be a breath of fresh air.

[image: Oracle EM Express]

Comment: As I have looked around for queries I found the following resource that looks promising.  https://oracle-base.com/dba/scripts

Answer (score 1):

Normally if I want to know what a particular process is doing I try to find out when it is going to run (or if it is currently running), find its session, and start an SQL trace on the session.  What have you done so far.

Comment: That is exactly what I have tried so far but have not been successful in capturing any SQL for this.